# Dataflow stops writting/publishing after an interval

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a dataflow pipeline non-stop running. It pulls data from a PubSub subscription and writes results into BigQuery as well as another PubSub topic. It works fine as I continually publish messages to the topic that it subscribes. After I stop publishing messages for hours and start it again, I can still see the number of inputs increase and the watermark proceeds from the web interface, but the wall time of the steps of PubSub publish and BigQuery write increases and there are not any messages being written. The data freshness of the pipeline keeps going up. I also cannot see any errors in the logs. What are the potential reasons behind?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in your question to figure out what the problem is. I'd advice you to try two things: 1) open a support ticket with GCP support; and 2) add more information/code about your pipeline, and perhaps add some logging to the transform upstream of BQIO

Comment: @Pablo thank you for the reply! I found that this problem is not valid because I screwed up the timestamp in the event: they are supposed to be in milliseconds while I mistakenly send them in seconds. This causes the watermark much behind and therefore it does not reach the end of a window. That explains why there is no firing. Still, I appreciate your tips. I'll take care of that next time I post a question.